# Extract specific columns in the row after each bold heading in HTML table use BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the text in column 1 and column 3 in the next row after the first and second bold headings in one html table using BeautifulSoup.The bold texts don't have classes or ids, and are at the same level as rows above and below them. I suppose I should use next_sibling, but I'm not sure how exactly to go about doing that.

You can find HTML of the table here: https://github.com/Tokaalmighty/topmover_table_html/blob/master/html

Here's my logic:

```
soup=bs(f1,'html.parser')
topmovers=soup.find('table',{'class':'topmovers'})

bold=topmovers.find_all('b')
gainer=bold[0]
gainer_name=bold.find('tr').next_sibling
gcol1=gainer_name[0]
gcol3=gainer_name[2]

loser=bold[1]
loser_name=bold.find('tr').next_sibling
lcol1=loser_name[0]
lcol3=loser_name[2]

print(gcol1,gcol3,lcol1,lcol3)
```

Comment: can you share the html structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`find_next`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-next-and-find-next) to select the next 'tr', then get the text with [`stripped_strings`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string-generators)

```
soup=bs(f1,'html.parser')
topmovers=soup.find('table',{'class':'topmovers'})

bold=topmovers.find_all('b')
gainer=bold[0]
gainer_name=gainer.find_next('tr')
gainer_strings = list(gainer_name.stripped_strings)
gcol1=gainer_strings[0]
gcol3=gainer_strings[2]

loser=bold[1]
loser_name=loser.find_next('tr')
loser_strings = list(loser_name.stripped_strings)
lcol1=loser_strings[0]
lcol3=loser_strings[2]

print(gcol1, gcol3, lcol1, lcol3)
```

> McDermott International 6.55 Bill Barrett Corporation 2.87